# Why my set approach works in some cases and failed in others?

Tags: python, set

[Leetcode 500](https://leetcode.com/problems/keyboard-row/)

I tried to solve with set in python .
for most case my code works.

```
class Solution:
def findWords(self, words: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    set_top = {'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'}
    set_mid = {'a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l'}
    set_low = {'z','x','c','v','b','n','m'}
    
    for i in words:
        set_i = set(i.lower())
        
        if set_i-set_top and set_i-set_mid and set_i-set_low :
            words.pop(words.index(i))
    
    return words
```

I dont know where i went wrong.
refer image for test case failed

[Test case 14 failed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf3qe.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing items from the same list you're iterating over.

Better would be to only collect the ones that do match, and return those:

```py
def answer():
    ...
    valid_words = []
    for word in words:
        if ...:
           valid_words.append(word)
    return valid_words
```

adding a couple of debugging prints shows this more clearly:

```py
In [81]: findWords(['abdfs', 'cccd', 'a', 'qwwewm'])
0: words = ['abdfs', 'cccd', 'a', 'qwwewm'], word=abdfs
removing abdfs: 0
1: words = ['cccd', 'a', 'qwwewm'], word=a
2: words = ['cccd', 'a', 'qwwewm'], word=qwwewm
removing qwwewm: 2
Out[81]: ['cccd', 'a']
```

It never actually checks `cccd` because you've fiddled with the list context and the iterator skips over it.

Comment: @vasudev see edited answer. Although there's probably no (good) reason to modify the list in place rather than do as I and the other commenters have said, and just return a new list with the filtered values.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem in one line by using `any()` function in combination with a composed list comprehension:

```
class Solution:
    def findWords(self, words: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        return [i for i in words if any(all(c in j for c in i.lower()) for j in ['qwertyuiop','asdfghjkl','zxcvbnm'])]
```

Comment: the OP probably wants to know what is wrong with his code, this isn't a answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks for your code bro. But can you tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @vasudev Was this answer useful?

Comment: Bro your code is very simple i would have never though of it. I trying to understand your code one by one . i find list comphrension difficult to understand. new to programming bro. But i run your program in leetcode , all test case passed. Thanks bro @Cardstdani

Comment: You could maybe use sets: `us_keyboard_rows = (frozenset("qwertyuiop"), frozenset("asdfghjkl"), frozenset("zxcvbnm")); word_letters = (set(w.lower()) for w in words); return [w for w, wl in zip(words, word_letters) if any(wl.issubset(r) for r in us_keyboard_rows)]`

Comment: @daniel-hao You're right, comprehensions are a bit strange for recent learners. But I think it encourages them to understand deeply the basis of loops and traversals.